# Asking for payment for a project that's gone over deadline (and still going)

Tags: client-relations

I agreed to a flat-fee project that was supposed to be completed in a week. The client has since dragged out this project for almost a month. Should I ask for payment for the original flat fee, despite the project not being complete yet? Contract only says that payment will be issued 30 days after completion.

The client is a large marketing firm, so they aren't strapped for cash like a small time client. Additionally, I am now on an hourly rate for everything going forward so there is that to consider.

Comment: It's tricky since your contract sounds like it isn't very specific about anything out of scope. Did you happen to include any stipulations about excessive changes by the client?

Comment: Is this the same client as in [your previous post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/78756/23061)?

Comment: Yes. No end in sight. Their contract doesn't have anything about if the project goes over the estimated duration.